# Links to typedef classes from the same namespace in groups missing

Tags: doxygen

when I create a C++ typedef within a namespace referencing a class from the same namespace Doxygen (tested with Version 1.8.9.1) will not create links to this class when I add it to a group page:

```
/// @defgroup test
/// @brief Test

namespace a
{
    class A
    {
    };

    /// @ingroup test
    typedef A    B;

    /// @ingroup test
    typedef a::A C;
}
```

On the generated group page the first typedef ("A to B") will have no link to A while the second ("a::A to C") will be correctly linked.

Is this a Bug in Doxygen? Are there workarounds to get the correct links without having to use fully qualified names?

Comment: without grouping it works fine, so looks like a bug indeed. I suggest to file a bug report here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen